# What happens to scheduled jobs set to half past midnight, when the clocks go forward or back?

Tags: scheduled-apex

Trust our team tester to think of this one!

When the clocks go forward in Spring there is no time from 00:00 to 01:00.
When the clocks go back that time period duplicates.

Is Salesforce clever enough to handle jobs scheduled in this time? Will the job still run once per night even on those nights, or will it skip a night in Spring or double up in Autumn?

Comment: Just FYI - In the US, the gap is between 02:00 and 03:00, not 00:00 and 01:00.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Impact of scheduled jobs due to fall of Day light savings

Knowledge Article Number: 000170765

Description
On Nov 4th, we have fall of day light savings. could you please let us know how is this handled in SFDC cloud. In general, clocks will be set back from 1:59AM to 1AM. In this case the jobs which are scheduled at 1AM will run twice on this day. Do we have the same impact in SFDC as well.

Resolution
The scheduled date time is in GMT, so the job is executed once.

Say the user is in GMT+5 (considering dailight savings), 1 am GMT+5 is 8pm GMT (previous day), so at 8 pm GMT the job is executed. When the day light savings stop applying at 2 am GMT+5 (9 pm GMT) the time for the user is displayed as 1 am GMT+4 (still 9 pm GMT). We don't go back in time, we just change the offset with GMT.

The same goes for the off set of the daylight saving Just apply the corresponding time offset in the time displayed to the user.

Here is link to Salesforce Knowledge Article https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000170765&language=en_US

Comment: TL;DR It runs as if scheduled in GMT, which has no DST observances, so "daily" is still once per day, "every other hour" is still 120 minutes of physical clock time as observed by a stopwatch, etc.

Comment: Thanks. So that means if a user in their +5 timezone asks for 1am, the system converts it to 8pm internally?

As an aside - we tried to see if there was a difference between 0/5 hours and */5 hours, as 5 is not a factor of 24. We wondered if the */5 would drift by an hour every day as it maintained 5 hours time between jobs. It did not, and behaved as 0/5 starting at midnight every day.

Comment: All times are stored in GMT anyways, so it seems natural that the scheduler would abide by the same rules. I'm not surprised that */5 results in a reset each midnight. The * most likely evaluates to 0 when used in a divisor. That does sound glitchy though.